# iTunes 12.2 blank tab, in the song section

Tags: itunes, software-update

Just updated to iTunes 12.2 and noticed that there is a blank column I would like to delete:

Is this possible to do? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the top bar where it's not blank, and see what columns you have turned on - it's going to be one of these:

[image: iTunes bar]

Actually on looking again, I think this is a duplicate of your Track number column. What happens if you toggle it off and back on?

If that doesn't work, try hitting the blank one and clicking "Auto Size Column", the label may then appear.

Comment: Yeah the track number just takes away "Track #" column but none of the options seem to turn off the blank area. What's funny is I can't autosize that one column instead only only get the option to autosize all columns. I guess this is just an odd glitch. Thanks for your help though.